# Lisp stack overflow bound

Tags: algorithm, lisp, stack-overflow

I really need an advice. I have a function that have big number of recursive calls. Actually i need it. And algorithm is correct it works in C but in lisp there is a problem because of stack overflow. What should i do to solve it? How can i change algorithm to be able to work in lisp?

Comment: That's really too broad a question to give a meaningful answer. Change your recursive algorithm into an iterative one or a tail-recursive one, is the most we can say.

Comment: Are you compiling the function? If so: Using what settings for `optimize`?

Comment: I see that in line 42 of the Lisp, you deviated from what the C is doing; you changed a key check in such a way that runaway recursion occurs. No wait, it's line 47! My crystal ball needs a new deflection coil; 2's are starting to look like 7's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Rewrite the algorithm to be tail-recursive or, equivalently, iterative
2. Change the algorithm all together
3. Increase the lisp's stack size

Comment: How to do 3rd option? Is it possible on Windows OS?

Comment: What lisp are you using?  What are the command arguments available?  What does the documentation say?